# Uso elevado del cpu con gulp watch en laravel

Tags: laravel-5, gulp

Buenas tardes. Como puedo evitar el uso del 50% de mi cpu al usar gulp watch con webpack o browserify en Laravel? :/ ademas browserSync no esta funcionando, las paginas no se actualizan y salen errores en la consola de chrome.

```
elixir(function(mix) {

  //mix.browserSync();

  mix.copy(
    'node_modules/bootstrap-sass/assets/javascripts/bootstrap.js',
    'resources/assets/js/elixir_copy_cache')
  .copy(
    'node_modules/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert-dev.js',
    'resources/assets/js/elixir_copy_cache')
  .copy(
    'node_modules/materialize-css/dist/js/materialize.js',
    'resources/assets/js/elixir_copy_cache');

  mix.sass('app.scss');

  mix.webpack([
    'app.js',
    'articles.js'
  ]);

});
```

Comment: Has probado desactivando alguno de esos componentes?

Comment: si, webpack es el causante del problema. No tiene sentido que en idle siga con un uso alto del cpu y lo de browserSync ni idea porque he entrado a su panel de control y nada funciona.